# No. of disk blocks writes required for writing the file

Tags: computer-architecture, database-theory, memory-hardware, filesystems

Assume that a file is written using write(fd, buf, K) system calls, where fd is the file descriptor, and K, the number of files to be written to the current file offset which is a multiple of the disk block size D. The total number of disk block writes required to be executed before the system call returns is:

(a) is equal to K/D

(b) is less than K/D

(c) is greater than K/D

(d) None of the above.

In my opinion, the answer should be (c). But the solution manual says it's (d).

I believe the number of file writes required for writing a file is $ceil(K/D)$
So, the answer should be (c).

Am I correct? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Think about it this way. Is any of the others *always* true? Is ceil(K/D) *always* greater than K/D, or *always* equal to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is: greater or equal to K/D, depending on the fact that K can be a multiple of D or not. So, the answer is actually c), which differs from the other three answers.

Note that if there were an answer “ceil(K/D)”, that would have been the correct answer.